# How should I read this type syntax?

Tags: types, read-eval-print-loop, idris

I'm reading through *Type-Driven Development with Idris*, and I ran into some confusing formatting while experimenting with the [`valToString`](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/type-driven-development-with-idris/chapter-1/247) function on page 23. Specifically, I added a function hole:

```
valToString : (x : Bool) -> StringOrInt x -> String
valToString x val = (?f val)
```

When I ask the REPL about the type of this hole, this is the printed result:

```
*Hello> :t f
  x : Bool
  val : case x of
          True => Int
          False => String
--------------------------------------
f : case x of   True => Int False => String -> String
Holes: Main.f
```

The type of `val` is readable enough here, but **how should I read the type of `f`**? The book mentions [on page 19](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/type-driven-development-with-idris/chapter-1/188) that whitespace is significant in Idris; would this be valid syntax if I were to use it for a type in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this has nothing to do with spaces. Just bad formatting.

This

```
f : case x of   True => Int False => String -> String
```

can be reformatted like this:

```
f : (case x of {True => Int; False => String}) -> String
```

When I type `:t f` in Idris repl this shows next thing to me:

```
*Hello> :t f
  x : Bool
  val : StringOrInt x
--------------------------------------
f : StringOrInt x -> String
Holes: Main.f
```

This case is just inlined version of type `StringOrInt x`. Though poorly formatted. Maybe older version of `Idris` was used when this chapter was written.

**UPDATE (23.07.2017)**

Unfortunately, not everyone have book :( I tried to guess type of `StringOrInt` but I didn't guess it precisely. I used next definition in my code:

```
StringOrInt : Bool -> Type
StringOrInt True  = Int
StringOrInt False = String
```

With this definition I get output from above. While in reality `StringOrInt` defined in the next way:

```
StringOrInt : Bool -> Type
StringOrInt x = case x of
    True => Int
    False => String
```

These two definitions semantically equivalent. Difference only syntactic. But apparently this leads to different compiler output for `:t f` command.

I've opened corresponding issue:

https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/3937

Comment: Thanks, your formatting makes much more sense! What version of Idris are you using that gives you that REPL output? The output in my question is from Idris 1.0. I don't believe that an older version was used for the book, as [the website](https://www.idris-lang.org/idris-1-0-released/) specifically says version 1.0 corresponds to the book. Although maybe I don't quite understand; could you clarify what you meant by that comment?

Comment: Actually, perhaps you're right about the Idris version used for the book: the `integerval + doubleval` example on page 28 references `Prelude.Classes.+`, while the Idris 1.0 REPL references `Prelude.Interfaces.+` instead.

Comment: @SamEstep I'm also using Idris 1.0. But 1.0 version of compiler was released at August 1st while book was released in March. This means that a lot of code was written even earlier. And it's possible those code snippets were generated using compiler without some patches from 1.0 version.

Comment: @SamEstep I've updated my answer. The problem is not in compiler version in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I apologize for not making the definition of `StringOrInt` clear; since the first chapter of the book is provided for free online, the `StringOrInt` function can be found at the link I gave in my question.